# Do these fluorescents contain ballast and starters?

Tags: lighting, industrial

I will probably buy some used fluorescent lamps to grow vegetables indoors for my project.

As I am aware fluorescent lamps need ballast and starter. I don't have experience with fluoresent lamps and I don't know if these used ones contain it as seen in picture.

I need to know what else will I need to make them work except cable and digital electric switch.

Edit:

I haven't got more photos, I haven't bought them yet, just looking at them in online marketplace.

[image: Fluorescent lights]

Comment: this is really a shopping question ... if the seller does not provide full information about the lamps, then do not buy them

Comment: Make sure that you can easily get GroLux bulbs or their equivalent in your country, and that you get fixtures that fit them.  These days I would expect that LED bulbs will be a better bet.

Comment: Note: A "starter" may or may not be part of the system. A starter works in conjunction with a magnetic ballast to provide a high-voltage spike that kicks the tube into conduction shortly after power is applied. But some ballasts (especially, modern "high-frequency electronic" ballasts) can do that without any need for a distinct starter component.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixtures are supposed to come with ballasts

The seller really ought to say "Ballast is gone, but I'm guessing  you'll convert to LED anyway so who cares".  You care.

That's a standard 2' x 2' **troffer** designed to fit in drop ceilings.

Most of them have U-bulbs, but yours has straight tubes, almost assuredly bog-standard F17T8 or F20T12 size.   They really look to my eyes like T8 (8/8" = 1" diameter). Regardless, we'll make it so.

Occasionally,  some mouth-breather will stick T8 tubes in a T12 fixture, but not change the ballast to T8. *That doesn't work very well*. In that case change the ballast to T8 which is vastly superior both in efficiency and performance.

### Don't listen to the naysayers. 21st century fluorescent is awesome.

*The 2000-10's have been really good to fluorescent tech.*  Those naysayers can play with their no-name Chinese LEDs with 70-80 CRI. Here, for the same price you get **top shelf** -- General Electric, Sylvania, Philips.  You can count on that stuff.

Given that you have T8, I suspect you have most of this tech.  T8 is a sweet spot between good efficiency (like T5) and good price/support (like T12). Expect no less than:

- No starter.
- Operates at a very high frequency so there's never any flicker.*
- No buzz/hum since it's not a transformer.
- Competent cold start and cold operation. (for regular cold-starts, get a *programmed start* ballast).
- Power factor at least 95%, *which helps if you power a lot of them*.*
- Multi-voltage from 120V-277V, *ditto*.
- If you need to replace tubes, accept nothing less than 90 CRI*.
- superior to common LEDs.  Who'd guess LEDs have a flicker problem?

Your T8 ballast probably already has all that.  If not, you can get one that does for under $20. (the GE 74463 is $11).

**Oh. Speaking of tube length.  You are better off getting 48" long fluorescent fixtures; they have better selection on both tube and ballast** (though 24" are available at sane price). I pay under $2 each for 48" 90CRI tubes.

**Density**.  If you need to think about lumens per square foot, the highest density is found in 48" 6-tube fixtures with 6 T8s. In the 2010s they were sold by the millions to replace 400W metal-halide lights in warehouse/retail lighting. Now they're being mass-junked as stores "upgrade" to LED (almost new fixtures, too).

### Selecting an appropriate ballast

Your fixture decides tube size (F17T8 or F20T12 for this fixture).  Then, your tube size decides ballast.

For any ballast, you have to drill down to its **spec sheet** for the *full and total* list of tubes it supports.  (the description and product label has a truncated list). The good news is, your F17T8 tubes are supported by some ballasts designed for F32T8 tubes, which are by far the most common size.  However most of these are 2-lamp ballasts.

The following differences are irrelevant to an "on 24x7" fluorescent (since most wear & tear is on startup). **Instant-start** means it strikes the arc with a huge shot of voltage, without bothering to preheat the tubes. This makes for shorter tube life.  **Rapid-start** means it does a fixed pre-heat before striking the arc.  **Programmed-start** means it preheats to correct/ideal temperature (almost instant on a hot day, 2-3 seconds during an arctic chill).  It's so good for tube life that you can use them on motion sensors.  IME instant-start is not necessarily cheaper.

**Ballast factor** is how much it underdrives or overdrives the tube. This is an aesthetic choice of how much light you want in the room.  It has nothing to do with power factor.

**One ballast, or two?**  Most 4-lamp fluorescents have mounting locations for 2 ballasts. That gives you the latitude to use one 4-lamp, or two 2-lamp ballasts.  (hi/lo switching, or broader selection of ballast in 2-lamp).  I only see one one 4-lamp ballast that supports F17T8: the GE 74463, which costs a measly $11, but is instant-start.

### Selecting tubes

I'm not a grower so I can't help you there.  I can tell you CRI is for humans not plants, *but again, 48" is the best tube length if you are after best selection at sane prices*.

I would expect your ideal grower tube to be sold in T8; **if it's only sold in T12 for some reason, make sure to get a T12 ballast.  Do not run T12 tubes on T8 ballasts.**

If you are buying exotic/expensive tubes, don't trust them to an old buzzy magnetic ballast, because one of their failure modes is to burn out tubes, so not good with an expensive tube. Mag ballasts should be swapped to electronic ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Big picture: It may not be worth the money, even if it's free.

Normally the fixture will contain the ballast and the starter, but you should check with the seller before you buy the fixture.

Now, know that ballasts have limited life. So if the fixture came from a tear-out there's a chance that even if it has the ballast in it, it may be old and in need of replacing. That's some money right there.

It also matters whether what you intend to grow as this influences your bulb choice. Is it a flowering or non-flowering plant? Flowering plants (like, *cough*, weed) need a warmer spectrum than non-flowering plants such as veggies. So you need to select the right bulbs to get the best results. Does the fixture have the right ones? Even if they are, are they old? That's more outlay.

More about that here: https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/hpgen/fluorescent-lighting-for-indoor-gardening.htm

And here: https://growlightinfo.com/what-kind-of-fluorescent-lights-to-grow-plants/

Say you take a pass on the fixture. What's better? High-pressure sodium (cheaper) or LED lighting (more efficient) for indoor growing projects. Both are more efficient than flourescent and have longer life.

Comment: HPS has Very Buzzy ballasts (I have 30 of em) and the technology became commercially dead before the electronic ballast age.  However, amusingly and ironically, you can get electronic ballasts *from the aftermarket*, specifically, the "grow light community" of all people!  Demand from growers has also launched the price of used HPS lights into the stratosphere.  I should sell mine lol.